# Vue & Firebase: Data being duplicated in state unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, state

I have two calls to Firebase: one to get the existing data and one to listen for updates in the data. When those updates happen, instead of replacing the existing data for some reason I see to be adding the two datasets together. Can't figure out why as I'm directly updating state with new data in my second function.

Here are the functions called on mounted():

```
mounted() {
   this.getImages();
   this.refreshImages();
},
```

And the two functions in question:

```
async getImages() {
  let snapshot = await db
    .collection("Maria")
    .orderBy("timestamp", "desc")
    .get();
  snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    let appData = doc.data();
    appData.id = doc.id;
    this.picturesData.push(appData);
  });
  this.dataLoaded = true;
},
async refreshImages() {
  await db
    .collection("Maria")
    .orderBy("timestamp", "desc")
    .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      let newPicturesData = [];
      snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        let newPictureData = doc.data();
        newPictureData.id = doc.id;
        newPicturesData.push(newPictureData);
      });
      this.picturesData = newPicturesData; // this should overwrite the data in my state, right? But instead it's appending.
    });
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to tell you exactly what's happening without thoroughly testing your code but you have to note that the two calls (to `getImages()` and `refreshImages()`) may not be done in the order you expect.

Since in `getImages()` you **push** the data to `picturesData` and in `refreshImages()` you **replace** `picturesData`, I suspect that the listener set through `refreshImages()` returns data before you get the result of the query triggered by `getImages()`.

---

Actually, since [`onSnapshot()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen?authuser=0#listen_to_multiple_documents_in_a_collection) triggers **an initial call that returns the entire result of the query**, you only need to call `refreshImages()` (you don't need the initial call to `getImages()`).

---

Note that `onSnapshot()` is not an asynchronous method like `get()`, so you don't need to make `refreshImages()` async.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Can you think of a way I can reverse that process? How can I ensure that the state update in `refreshImages()` happens **after** the first get in `getImages()`?

I've removed the async notation from `refreshImages()` but that didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Actually, I've just realised that you only need the `refreshImages()` method! (I'm doing several things in parallel and it didn't immediately pop to my head!! :-)). See the updated answer.

Comment: You may also be interested by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58276739/3371862